# No package found in the current package source

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

This must be a simple issue, but don't see what is wrong. Managing packages form VS2012 the dialog opens but there seems to be no online packages available: "No package found in the current package source". The package source is:

```
https://nuget.org/api/v2/
```

Is this the correct setting, is there something else missing? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did install several packages, previously. Got the NuGet Package Manager V2.2.40116.9051 and MS VS 2012 Premium V 11.0.511606.01 (update 1), in case it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Bizarre, I added an extra (no-existing) package source (via settings), enabled both. No effect. But after removing the newly added entry, everything works fine again. Enjoy!